# javascript id calling in angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, angular

I have two files, app.js and mycomponent.html. The problem is that the category is not being called and giving no response or error.

```
<select id="category" name="c">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">Rent</option>
  <option value="2">Buy</option>
  <option value="3">Commercial rent</option>
  <option value="4">Commercial buy</option>
</select>
```

```js
$('#category').on('change', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    var id = e.target.value;
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Is this actually Angular 4? There's no Angular template syntax and the JavaScript is using jQuery...

Comment: Angular + jQuery? I'm not surprised event is not bound. Lifecycle.. I bet `$('#category').length === 0` when you bind it.

Comment: $(document.body).on('change','#category',function(){
    console.log(e.target.value);
    var id = e.target.value;
});

Comment: yes! I am working on angular 4

Comment: there is no angular in this piece of code

Comment: This is not Angular and it has nothing to do with Angular. If you're using Angular like you demonstrated in this question than you might just use jQuery altogether

Comment: If you just want the value of your particular code then do the following;     $('#category').on('change', function() {
            id = $(this).val();
        });

Answer (score 1):

Please, stop using jQuery everywhere.

You never need to use jQuery with Angular 2+. Use Angular instead.

See how to work with [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix angular and jQuery.

Visit angular.io or others for getting basics.